# What would be the best way to correlate logs and events on several hosts?

Tags: linux, log-files

I'm trying to build a log correlation system on multiple hosts.

SEC seems interesting but I don't know if it will cover my needs.

How could I correlate system events, logs, network events, etc. on multiple hosts at the same time, in real time?

Examples:

> If 5 failed logins happened on host A the last minute and if firewall B has denied lots of access on differents ports on A, then we assume there is a potential attack in progress on A.
>
> If the Apache service on host A didn't receive any request for the last N minutes and Apache service on host B did, then the load balancing could be faulty.

Answer (score 0):

I would use a central syslog server in combination with fail2ban:

[Fail2Ban Website](http://www.fail2ban.org/wiki/index.php/Main_Page)

[Creating a central syslog server](http://www.linuxjournal.com/content/creating-centralized-syslog-server)

> Fail2ban scans log files (e.g. /var/log/apache/error_log) and bans IPs that show the malicious signs -- too many password failures, seeking for exploits, etc. Generally Fail2Ban is then used to update firewall rules to reject the IP addresses for a specified amount of time, although any arbitrary other action (e.g. sending an email) could also be configured. Out of the box Fail2Ban comes with filters for various services (apache, courier, ssh, etc).

On the otherside you could use an IDS or an IPS. There are free ones too like SNORT.

[Snort Website](http://www.snort.org/)

But this one needs a lot of administration, a central network monitoring (maybe a central switch) and KnowHow, but you can cover lots of more events. Maybe (I havent done this before) you can use a finished distribution with SNORT and SNORBY:

[Snorby Website](https://snorby.org/)

Comment: Thank you for your answer, but I'm not only looking for a security tool. I know fail2ban, but this is not what I want to do. I want to correlate logs and events to be able to deduce interesting facts for the system administrator (such as: "database server is not responding due to cpu overload caused by too many requests")

Comment: I think this can be done with fail2ban in a centralised system..
But here is another alternative - what about Nagios: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nagios

It is open source and you can monitor all kind of systems and processes:
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File:Monitoring.png